Reference request -- distributions on Lie groups and enveloping algebras
I am looking for a reference detailing the convolution algebra of distributions on a Lie group supported at the identity and its isomorphism with the universal enveloping algebra of the associated Lie algebra (as mentioned ex. on Wikipedia here). In particular, I am interested in the details of:

The precise definition of the distributions in question (ex. tempered/compactly supported)

The definition of convolution of distributions (as I have seen it only defined for a distribution and a test function)

Are there any conditions on the group (ex. locally compact/abelian)?


I will be most happy with a reference, but answers to the specific questions would also be appriciated!
(I have seen this mathoverflow answer, but it unfortunately does not explain the convolutions nor details of any of the objects used)
